# Missing columns with ParseInstallation object and saveInBackground()

Tags: android, parse-platform

In our Android application we are using Parse (along GCM) to push notifications to our users.

To do so we register each device with the following code:

```
ParseInstallation parseInstallation = ParseInstallation.getCurrentInstallation();

parseInstallation.put("GCMSenderId", gcmSenderId);
parseInstallation.put("preferredLanguage", language);
parseInstallation.put("deviceBrand", brand);
parseInstallation.put("deviceModel", model);
parseInstallation.put("androidSDK", version);

parseInstallation.saveInBackground(new SaveCallback()
{
    @Override
    public void done(ParseException e)
    {
        if (e == null)
        {
            Log.d(TAG, "Saving ParseInstallation succeeded");
        }
        else
        {
            Log.e(TAG, "Saving ParseInstallation failed");
        }
    }
});
```

All device are correctly registered on Parse, except that most of them (rougly 90%) aren't filling in the additionals columns.

Example: on 2000 devices, only 180 of them have correctly registered all needed data.

The successfull devices specs ranges go from:

- API: 16 -> 22
- Brand: Samsung, Google, HTC, OnePlus, LG, Motorola...
- And possibly every other possible specs

I have been looking through most of the things that came to my mind (documentation, Parse forums, SO...), but haven't found so far any logical reasons to this problem.

Is this a common problem or something specific to my application ?

Comment: Are you sure that your properties (`gcmSenderId`, `model`, etc) are not null for all the devices?

Comment: Yes I ensure, for every field, that the minimum value is an empty String object.

Comment: did you put the Permissions  to read phone data